# Criteria API is not generating left outer join

Tags: java, jpa, left-join, openjpa

I have 3 entities, infact many more joined together for brevity i'm skipping those and i'm using open jpa 2.2.2 and oracle 11g. Any thoughts what's going wrong here?

```
Entity SystemRules{
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "systemRule", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ServiceActionMap> serviceActionMap;
}

Entity ServiceActionMap{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SYSTEM_RULE_ID")
    private SystemRules systemRule;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RFS_TYPE_ID", nullable = true)
    private RfsTypeMap rfsType;
}

Entity RfsTypeMap{
    @Id
    @Column(name="RFS_TYPE_ID" ,nullable=false)
    private BigDecimal rfsTypeId;

    @Column(name="RFS_NAME")
    private String rfsName;
}
```

Now, I am trying to order the result by RfsTypeMap.rfsName, i'm creating query using criteria builder in following manner

```
CriteriaQuery<SystemRules> query = cb.createQuery(SystemRules.class);
Root<SystemRules> root= query.from(SystemRules.class);
root.fetch(SystemRules_.serviceActionMap).fetch(ServiceActionMap_.rfsType, JoinType.LEFT);
```

My order by clause is like this

```
cb.desc(cb.upper(systemRules.get("serviceActionMap").get("rfsType").get("rfsName").as(String.class)));
```

Generate JPQL looks like, where i expect a left outer join clause between ServiceActionMap and RfsTypeMap but it's missing. Same gets translated in SQL and i miss those records which are having  ServiceActionMap.rfsType as null value.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT s FROM SystemRules s INNER JOIN FETCH s.serviceActionMap  INNER JOIN FETCH s.serviceActionMap  INNER JOIN FETCH s.ruleProperty  INNER JOIN FETCH s.ruleProperty where ... ORDER BY UPPER(s.serviceActionMap.rfsType.rfsName)
```

I tried going over several answers here but no success, tried explicitly putting a where clause for ServiceActionMap.rfsType is null as suggested on few answers but it's getting ignored, since join happens before where evaluation. Somewhere this question [openJPA outer join on optional many-to-one when have order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845889/openjpa-outer-join-on-optional-many-to-one-when-have-order-by-clause) matches my scenario but not able to generate suggested JPQL through criteria API.

I found one related bug on apache jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2318. But, not sure that's the case.

Comment: There is NO guarantee that a FETCH join will be used, since it is just there to fetch and a JPA provider is perfectly within its rights to do it in an additional SQL call (since often somehow magically fetching every field possible would lead to way too complicated SQL). If it had been a JOIN without the fetch then it should use it

Comment: even with join, its not always using left join between these two tables. Why not always, because in some case when i used fetch and join both together(something like table a join a.b and table a fetch a.c), it used left join correctly between a & b and inner join between a & c. But when i tried (table a join a.b and table a join a.c), it followed inner join between all 3 tables a, b & c. Ordering by the join column is working well(results with left join) but not with other attributes of right side table(it always produces inner join).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that every join is repeated twice and even the join alias is always referring to SystemRules. It might be that orderby has caused the repeating inner joins and we may need to explicitly use Join object to refer to extended column.

```
CriteriaQuery<SystemRules> query = cb.createQuery(SystemRules.class);
Root<SystemRules> root = query.from(SystemRules.class);
Join<SystemRules, ServiceActionMap> join1 = root.join(SystemRules_.serviceActionMap, JoinType.INNER);
Join<ServiceActionMap, RfsTypeMap> join2 = join1.join(ServiceActionMap_.rfsType, JoinType.LEFT);
query.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.upper(join2.get(RfsTypeMap_.rfsName))));
```

Comment: I didn't get this part. 
`Join<ServiceActionMap, RfsTypeMap> join2 = join1.join(SRfsTypeMap_.rfsType, JoinType.LEFT);`
Is SRfsTypeMap_ metamodel class for RfsTypeMap? If yes, then it won't allow me to join over a field from RfsTypeMap_.rfsTypeId. Below is my meta model class.
`public class RfsTypeMap_ {
 public static volatile SingularAttribute<RfsTypeMap, BigDecimal> rfsTypeId;
 public static volatile SingularAttribute<RfsTypeMap, String> rfsName;`

Comment: Ah..my bad. It was supposed to be ServiceActionMap metamodel. corrected it.